# Potential Bug: Accidental Downvote gives "Critic" badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I accidentally downvoted an answer but quickly undid the action and upvoted it - which I intended to do first anyway. Whilst the reputation has balanced out properly and everything is back to normal, I have now been awarded the "Critic" badge - even though I haven't actually properly downvoted an answer.

Is this intended behaviour (essentially a free bronze badge to those who want it) or a bug?

Comment: Generally badges, once earned, are never taken back.

Comment: I don't think this is too severe an issue... any user of the site is going to cast up- and down-votes and get those badges pretty soon anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended behavior. You cast a downvote, whether or not it stuck. You can do the same with Supporter, for what it's worth.

Comment: And autobiographer

Comment: i downvoted plenty of questions/answers and my critic badge is still not awarded